# Do both A and B + [verb]

Tags: questions

I want to ask the following question:

> Do both A and B refer to C?

Is this the right way to do so? I don't know why but it sounds a little unnatural to me.

Is there another way?

Thank you.

Comment: Is this a mathematical question? If not, I think some examples might make it easier to determine what you mean. If so, then yeah, that looks like a reasonable sentence about a mathematical kind of question.

Comment: No it's not a mathematical question.

Comment: An example sentence would still help, so we can get a concrete sample of what you are talking about.

Comment: Yes, I'm still unable to tell whether that's a reasonable construction without an example sentence or two. It looks promising, but...

Comment: @A.Beth Do both "mutually exclusive" and "exhaustive" refer to the medical data sets?

Comment: Okay, with that sentence, yeah, that's fine. You could also put "both" next to "refer" -- "Do 'mutually exclusive' and 'exhaustive' both refer to the medical data sets?" (I would tend to keep "both refer" together when using longer words, but for very short words, it could go next to either "do" or "refer" with no problems. E.g., "Do both 'cat' and 'dog' refer to 'pets'?")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is clear and sounds natural to me.

> Do A and B refer to C?

Has the same meaning, but the *both* would help make the logical relationships clear.

Some people, especially in speech, and especially in a casual register, would say

> Do A and B both refer to C?

But most people would prefer your wording, especially in writing, and certainly in formal discourse.